# Connect MYSQL Database stored on local system With android app

Tags: android, mysql, database, sql-server-2008

So, the scenario is i have a MYSQL database stored on local system on SQL server 2008 which is turned ON 24/7 and is connected to internet. there is no API, no web services.

Now, i want to develop a android application which can fetch data from that server. and that app should be able to get the data no matter from where the app is getting accessed.

i somewhere read that it is possible by connecting via IP address but could't find proper reference for it and i never done it before.

i can connect android app if the database is stored on cloud but this one is on local system.
so tell me the possible ways to connect android app with local database. i've already spent plenty of time in searching the solution but nothing is helpful.